# are the terms level and height only defined for trees, not graph? what about size?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

Is the level of a vertex only defined for a tree, not a graph? How about height and size?

Comment: Why -1. Please explain. This is unacceptable!

Comment: I think it is because of punctuation and 'pls give link. thnks'. If you had written it slightly different, you wouldn't have got downvotes

Comment: @Harmen: I think you're right, which is a bit sad really.  Personally the "don't bother with capital letters, punctuation or full words" style grates on me, but I have to admit the question is perfectly clear.

Comment: Ok. I have changed the punctuation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, level and size are only defined for rooted trees.  (In graph theory, trees do automatically have a specified root node.)  If by size you mean the number of nodes, then yes, that is defined for all graphs.  In computer science, "tree" usually refers to what graph theory calls an arborescence, which is a rooted directed tree in which all edges point away from the root.  All of these terms can be looked up in Wikipedia.

Answer (score 2):

The size of a graph is the number of its edges. The number of vertices is called *order*. A graph does not normally have a height, but a diameter and a radius (all three can be defined in terms of eccentricity).

[Wikipedia: Glossary of graph theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory)

Answer (score 0):

Researched a lot and found the following:

Level, Height defined only for rooted trees

Just want to clarify Adam's answer. It is not necessary that a tree automatically has a root. You can have free trees also which have no root.

Comment: This statement confuses me.  Would you provide a link which demonstrates a root-less tree?

Comment: @David In graph theory, a tree is a connected undirected graph that does not have any circles (in other words, once you remove an edge, the resulting graph is not connected anymore). In such a graph, any vertex can be considered a root. But if any vertex can be considered a root, it does not make sense to introduce the term *root*.